# Installing Apache 2.2

Tags: apache, installation

So I am following the directions and I did:

```
./configure --prefix=/fmac/users/f****/apacheServer \
  --exec-prefix=/fmac/users/f*****/apaacheServer
```

and it seems to work no errors or anything.

Then I do:

```
make
make install
```

And i get the following error on install:

```
libtool: install: error: cannot install `libaprutil-1.la' to a directory not
                         ending in /usr/local/apache2/lib
```

Any ideas why is there some other config var i need to set?

Comment: This question would probably get more attention at ServerFault (http://serverfault.com), as it isn't strictly related to programming.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

In case anyone searches on Google for this answer, I figured out how to fix it. I had to:

`make clean`

in my `httpd-NN` build root directory (where NN is the version of httpd you are building).

And then it worked.

Comment: Worked perfectly for me too, in the case of something else than Apache.

Answer (score 0):

This thing worked for me:

if you are installing apache,apr,apr-util at a different location (other than the default one) and don't have root rights then you need to configure apache as:

```
./configure  --prefix=path/to/your/apachefolder --with-apr=/path/for/apr -with-apr-util=/path/for/apr-util --with-pcre=/path/for/pcre
```

This worked for me . I hope this helps.